# Notification bar content and scroll down

Tags: screen, notification-bar, home-screen

When I swipe the notification bar down, I get a bunch of "**items**", roughly one for each notification (email, weather, news &c). How are these items called? How do I control their verbosity?

Specifically, the "item" corresponding to Google Podcasts used to be "big" and contain the control buttons (stop, ff &c) and now I need to touch a tiny down arrow to get those buttons. How do I get back the whole thing?

Comment: Technically, the "item" is called "notification" on the [official Android Developer guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications). But since you mentioned the control button, perhaps you might also be referring to [media controls](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-controls).

Comment: Hello. Can you post a screenshot and circle the things you are asking about? That would bring clarity.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, you want all those buttons etc of those notifications to be available without clicking an extra tiny down arrow. You can maybe change the app's notification priorities under notification settings. See if that works.

If it doesn't there's nothing much you can do. Its a decision made to make a more compact User Interface as far as I know.

Comment: no, the app's notification settings do not help.

Comment: do you know what the _name_ of those items / buttons is?